# Events does not fire in Wordpress. Any Idea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I dont get my code working in Wordpress. It works fine if I run it outside of Wordpress, inside of it, it just wont work.

```
function init(){
    //setting global variables
    console.log("Init()");
    filelist = jQuery("#file-list");
    console.log(filelist);
    filecache = jQuery('#file-cache');
    console.log(filecache);
    fileInput = jQuery('#form-field-files');

    fileInput.on('change', function(){ console.log("Works"); });
    console.log(jQuery._data( fileInput, "events" ));

}
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  init();
});
```

Output is following:

```
Init()
n.fn.init [div#file-list, context: document, selector: "#file-list"]
n.fn.init [input#file-cache, context: document, selector: "#file-cache"]
n.fn.init [input#form-field-files.elementor-field.elementor-size-., context: document, selector: "#form-field-files"]0: input#form-field-files.elementor-field.elementor-size-.context: documentlength: 1selector: "#form-field-files"__proto__: Object(0)
undefined
```

When trying to triggering the event by selecting a File, it wont fire.

Does anyone have a Idea why it wont work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you explain what we are seeing in the output you posted? What does the undefined stand for? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: The Output is the Console Output. The undefined is the Output of "jQuery._data( fileInput, "events" )" Which should give me all events for the File Input

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is a init in the WordPress kit. I would try to rename the init function just for testing...